# Get first element in array and return using Aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**How can I get and return the first element in an array using a Mongo aggregation?**

I tried using this code:

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        resp : { my_field: { $slice: 1 } }
    }}
])
```

but I get the following error:

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$slice'",
    "code" : 15999,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Note that `'my_field'` is an array of 4 elements, and I only need to return the first element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, the `$slice` operator is unavailable in the the `$project` operation, of the aggregation pipeline.
So what you could do is,

First `$unwind`, the `my_field` array, and then group them together and take the `$first` element of the group.

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$my_field"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","resp":{$first:"$my_field"}}},
{$project:{"_id":0,"resp":1}}
])
```

Or using the `find()` command, where you could make use of the $slice operator in the `projection` part.

```
db.my_collection.find({},{"my_field":{$slice:1}})
```

**Update**: based on your comments, Say you want only the `second` item in an array, for the record with an id, `id`.

```
var field = 2;
var id = ObjectId("...");
```

Then, the below aggregation command gives you the 2nd item in the `my_field` array of the record with the `_id`, `id`.

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{$match:{"_id":id}},
{$unwind:"$my_field"},
{$skip:field-1},
{$limit:1}
])
```

The above logic cannot be applied for more a record, since it would involve a `$group`, operator after `$unwind`. The `$group` operator produces a single record for all the records in that particular group making the `$limit` or `$skip` operators applied in the later stages to be ineffective.

A small variation on the `find()` query above would yield you the expected result as well.

```
db.my_collection.find({},{"my_field":{$slice:[field-1,1]}})
```

Apart from these, there is always a way to do it in the client side, though a bit costly if the number of records is very large:

```
var field = 2; 
db.my_collection.find().map(function(doc){
return doc.my_field[field-1];
})
```

Choosing from the above options depends upon your data size and app design.

Comment: You answered my question without solving my problem unfortunately. I was in need of a generic aggregate, in which a parameter defines which element of `$my_field` I'll return. I try add `$skip`, but it isn't a `$group` operator.

Comment: See my updated answer. Anyway i thought my initial post had answered your question. If you required more clarification, you can always update your question or add a new question.

Answer (score 28):

Since 3.2, we can use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to get the first element in an array

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        resp : { $arrayElemAt: ['$my_field',0] }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the aggregation operator [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/first-array-element/) can be used to access the first element of an array:

```
// { "my_field": ["A", "B", "C"] }
// { "my_field": ["D"] }
db.my_collection.aggregate([
  { $project: { resp: { $first: "$my_field" } } }
])
// { "resp" : "A" }
// { "resp" : "D" }
```

Answer (score 1):

The $slice operator is scheduled to be made available in the $project operation in Mongo 3.1.4, according to this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074

This will make the problem go away.

This version is currently only a developer release and is not yet stable (as of July 2015). Expect this around October/November time.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo 3.1.6 onwards,

```
db.my_collection.aggregate([
{ 
    "$project": {
        "newArray" : { "$slice" : [ "$oldarray" , 0, 1 ] }
    }
}
])
```

where `0` is the start index and `1` is the number of elements to slice