# matching two string object fields in mongo aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
> db.doc.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55669401a5f628a23fed5adc"),
    "cur" : {
        "pathname" : "/blog",
        "href" : "http://www.example.com/blog/"
    },
    "visits" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/blog/",
            "gt_ms" : "1110"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556697eba5f628a23fed5add"),
    "cur" : {
        "pathname" : "/twcontroller/insights/login.php",
        "href" : "http://www.example.com/twcontroller/insights/login.php"
    },
    "visits" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/twcontroller/insights/login.php",
            "gt_ms" : "990"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556697eba5f628a23fed5ade"),
    "cur" : {
        "pathname" : "/",
        "href" : "http://www.example.com/"
    },
    "visits" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "719"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "719"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556697eba5f628a23fed5adf"),
    "cur" : {
        "pathname" : "/",
        "href" : "http://www.example.com/"
    },
    "visits" : [
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        },
        {
            "url" : "http://www.example.com/",
            "gt_ms" : "62"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to match the value of `cur.pathname` with the `visits[0].url` (*i.e., the first item in the array visits*) and returns its count. Also want to return the count of visits array which is having only one array element.

How can I do this?

Comment: Looking at your sample documents if you compare `cur.pathname` and `visits[0].url` it will always yield `False`. Did you mean `cur.href` and `visits[0].url` ?

Comment: I need the first url  value in visits array, means value of url at first index. like visits[0].url in JS

Comment: You can use the [`$slice`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#slice-projection) operator in projection or have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762887/get-first-element-in-array-and-return-using-aggregate-mongodb) to do it in aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Array Position Operator is not available for aggregation. There is an unresolved open issue linked to it: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4588 and https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4589 .

You will have to use the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to project the first element of array. 
This following query should give you the result you want. (I am assuming you want to compare `cur.href` and  `visits[0].url`.)

```
db.Testing.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "hasOneElement": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [{"$size": "$visits"}, 1] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            },
            "href": "$cur.href",
            "visits.url" : 1
        }
    },
    {'$unwind': '$visits'},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': "$_id",
        'href': {'$first': '$href'}, 
        'visits': {'$first': '$visits'},
        'hasOneElement': {'$first': '$hasOneElement'} 
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'hasOneElement': 1,
            "isMatch": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$href", "$visits.url"] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id' : 'test',
            'visit_count' : {'$sum' : '$isMatch' },
            'oneelement_count' : {'$sum' : "$hasOneElement" }
        }
    }
])
```

Result for Sample Document Supplied.

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "test",
            "visit_count" : 4,
            "oneelement_count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```