# $mod only supports numeric types, not array and int in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have this document structure in my collection:

```
{
  "grades": [
        { "grade": "A", "score": 8 },
        {"grade": "A", "score": 7 }
    ]
}
```

I need to filter for those documents when their `score` is divided by 7 has 0 as a reminder. Original question is asked [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/#MongoDB_restaurants) (question 30). Their solution is simple:

```
db.restaurants.find(
                  {"grades.score" :
                     {$mod : [7,0]}
                  },
                     {"restaurant_id" : 1,"name":1,"grades":1}
                );
```

However, in order to practice, I wanted to to my own solution, which doesn't work out.

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
           "$expr": {"$in": [0,   [ { $mod: [ "$grades.score", 7 ] }    ]  ]}
        }
    },
])
```

The error is:

```
PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $mod only supports numeric types, not array and int
```

Basically I want to check if 0 is in custom made array which will contain only single value after modulo operation, as explained in the [docs for $in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#mongodb-expression-exp.-in) when used in aggregation.

Is there a way to make `$mod` work as part of aggregation?

I see that similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241080/mongodb-mod-operator-in-aggregation-pipeline), but it is only referencing first score in grades array not all of them. So in my case I should see example document given on the beginning, since `7 % 7 = 0`

Comment: Worth noting that `{ "grades.score" : { $mod : [7,0] } }` is better since you don't have to actually write any loop logic or current value steps, etc. My answers below were wrt _"I wanted to to my own solution"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`$map`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) function to *map* each value of the array to the modulo result, and then check for 0 being in the resulting array.

You can use one of these:

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      mods: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$grades.score",
          "as": "score",
          "in": {
            $mod: ["$$score", 7]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$in": [0, "$mods"]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z5ewkjCob2N)

And if you want that as a single stage within the pipeline:

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$in": [
          0,
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$grades.score",
              "as": "score",
              "in": {
                $mod: ["$$score", 7]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L23AhrBNd_9)

Comment: Would it be correct to say that second query is more efficient because of the possibility to use indexes?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say that. You can use indexes in both. Mongo doesn't have _purely functional_ loops for [`$anyElementTrue`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/anyElementTrue/) or [`$all`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) which shortcut or "exit early". Both require the array to fully exist first anyway. Also, calculating the `mods` as a separate field first vs within the `$match` doesn't provide much  benefit. At most, if you were iterating over results, they would produce each batch sooner but the total time would be the same.

Comment: With indexes, you would need to know which index has a 0-modulo result anyway, so you still need to calculate all of them. In theory, you could use the [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) function to do fewer "calculations" but it would still iterate over the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative with [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) which may skip some calculations when a `0` modulo is found but would still iterate over the whole array anyway. In this case, since the modulo calculation is very efficient, it's unlikely to actually give any real benefit unless you had very *very* long lists of grades.

```js
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      final_modulo: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$grades.score",
          initialValue: 1,
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: { $eq: [ "$$value", 0] },
              // in theory, once we have a 0
              // don't calculate mods or the minimums any more
              then: "$$value",
              else: { $mod: ["$$this", 7] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { final_modulo: 0 } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground with more example data](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZiXkG7BBOiE)

Also I skipped the `{ $min: [{ $mod: ["$$this", 7] }, "$$value"] }` since we're only checking for **zero vs non-zero remainder**. And in case scores are negative, the [modulo minimum would be negative](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/#negative-dividend-1):

> The `$mod` expression produces a negative result when the dividend is negative.